# Jekyll on Heroku: bundler: command not found: thin

Tags: heroku, jekyll, thin

Working from a tutorial at http://mwmanning.com/2011/11/29/Run-Your-Jekyll-Site-On-Heroku.html. When I try to push to heroku I get a "build failed" message in the output.

Heroku logs shows

```
2013-01-30T05:29:54+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-30T05:31:36+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/rack app
2013-01-30T05:31:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-01-30T05:31:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -p 14276 -e $RACK_ENV`
2013-01-30T05:31:53+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2013-01-30T05:31:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2013-01-30T05:31:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1272013-01-30T05:31:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Gemfile and Gemfile.lock both show that thin is installed.

```
source :rubygems

gem 'jekyll'
gem 'rdiscount'
gem 'rack-jekyll'
gem 'thin'
gem 'RedCloth'
```

Command `bundle exec thin start` works locally and `bundle show thin` shows that thin is installed specifically for the current gemset.

I can't understand why heroku still says that thin is missing?

Answer (score 1):

For me a local `bundle update` fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not a direct answer. But this method worked for me.

http://chriscontinanza.com/2011/06/15/Jekyll-to-heroku.html